# Compiling with konanc behind proxy

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native

How to specify proxy settings for konanc?

I tried to start it with

```
konanc hello.kt -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800
```

and also tried to specify system variable at Windows

```
set JAVA_FLAGS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=10.0.0.100 -Dhttp.proxyPort=8800
```

but it fails on

Download native dependencies…

with `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
set JVM_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttp.proxyPort=yyy -Dhttps.proxyHost=xxx -Dhttps.proxyPort=yyy
```

It worked for me. Many repositories are using https, not only http.

Answer (score 0):

In OS X or Linux, with kotlin native version 1.0.2, use environment variable `JAVA_OPTS` to append custom JVM settings.

```
$ export JAVA_OPTS='-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy-host -Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy-port -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy-host -Dhttps.proxyPort=proxy-port'
```